# JFrame background disappears after start

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint

So I'm not exactly sure where the problem lies I set Jframe background with

```
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.green);
```

but, once the program starts it shows a flash of green then it's gone.

Game.java

```
package com.questkings.game;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JPanel{

Player player = new Player(this);

public Game(){
    addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
            player.keyReleased(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            player.keyPressed(e);
        }
    });
    setFocusable(true);
}

public void move(){
    player.move();
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    player.paint(g2d);
}

public void timer1() throws InterruptedException{
     int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
      ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          }
      };
      new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();;

Thread.sleep(10);
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, Exception{
    int Width = 800;
    int Height = 400;
    Game game = new Game();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("quest Kings");
    frame.setSize(Width, Height);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.green);
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setResizable(false);


    //What to do after the program starts
    while(true){
        game.move();
        game.repaint();
        game.timer1();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) `Thread.sleep(10);` Why is that in the code?

Comment: `while(true){ .. }` Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: @AndrewThompson **while(true)** should not block EDT because it's called in main thread.

Comment: What is the downside of if I just wrote a new Rectangle for my dimensions in the background?

Comment: You do realize that your `while(true)` loop is creation a gazillion Swing timer instances

Comment: Now I do and I am looking for a solution to that. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while(true) {...}` loop block main thread, that is why this happens. Try to use `worker` to perform this kind of operations in separate thread.

This link might be helpful:

[SWING WORKER EXAMPLE](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/)

Comment: **while(true)** is called in "main"-thread, why should it block EDT?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an advice, set the color of the application **directly** from the content pane, like that

```
contentPane.setBackground(Color.red);
```